# How to support tabs on Android 2.2+?

Tags: android, tabs

I'm trying to offer tab support for all Android versions 2.2 and above. Is there a way of achieving this without using any deprecated classes/methods?

Comment: use tabs in your application.

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated. I specifically asked if there was a way of doing this without using anything deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is as following: 
TabActivity is deprecated because it derives from [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) which is deprecated, too. Problems are, to start Activitys inside Tabs and don't break callbacks like `onActivityResume`. There are some 'Hacks' around which solve this but they are ALL relying on the deprecated [LocalActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html). So I see no solution of using `Tabs` without ANY deprecated calls. Since Android 3.X google invented [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) for this kind of things which are supported on lower Versions with the [SupportPackage](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). You should definetly try them in Combination with the new [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) if you want to avoid deprecated classes/methods

EDIT: 
Link to [FragmentTabs](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) for further reference

Comment: Found an answer in the support v4 API samples (FragmentTabs).

Answer (score 2):

I recon with with the answer Rafael gave.

Instead of resorting to the TabActivity you can sill use the regular TabHost to show tabs in all versions of android.

Comment: You are right. But If one is using TabHost he should be aware to fill TabSpecs with Intents cause at the end you are dealing with LocalActivityManager to keep the proper state of the Activitys, If you want to launch Activitys INSIDE the TabHosts'FrameLayout. Thats the reason I prefer Fragments a hundred times over ActivityGroups.

Comment: Yeah that is a good point. In the end it depends on what you want to do with the tabs

Comment: @Rafael T: can you do that? have activities as the contents of a TabHost (by using the support package sample)?